# Loop for calculating correlation coefficient for selected groups

Tags: r

I have numerous data frames with numerous variable pairs, for which I would like to calculate the correlation coefficient. I have been able to write a `function` and a `mapply` function to automate this process, but this only works for the entire dataset, not a defined subset of the dataset.

Below is an example dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:16)
df$VarA <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,14,14,14,14,16)
df$VarB <- c(10,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,0,14,14,14,16,16,16,16)
df$VarC <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$VarD <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$New_VarA <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$New_VarB <- c(10,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,0,14,14,14,16,16,16,16)
df$New_VarC <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$New_VarD <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$ControlVarA <- factor(c("Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_1", "Group_1",
                           "Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2",
                           "Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2")) 
df$ControlVarB <- factor(c("Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_1", "Group_1",
                           "Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2",
                           "Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2")) 
df$ControlVarC <- factor(c("Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_1", "Group_1",
                           "Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2",
                           "Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2")) 
df$ControlVarD <- factor(c("Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_1", "Group_1",
                           "Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2",
                           "Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2"))
```

I have written a `function` to calculate R2, and a function for calculating R2 across variable pairs (which I refer to as `R2_df`)using the code below. I then define the variable lists and use the `mapply` function to successfully calculate the R2 values for each pair of variables.

```
R2 = function(y_actual,y_predict){
  cor(y_actual,y_predict)^2
}

R2_df <- function(dataset, x, y){
  R2(dataset[[x]], dataset[[y]])
}

Var_list <- df %>% select(starts_with("Var")) %>% colnames()
New_Var_list <- df %>% select(starts_with("New")) %>% colnames()
Control_list <- df %>% select(starts_with("ControlVar")) %>% colnames()

mapply(R2_df, Var_list, New_Var_list, MoreArgs = list(dataset = df))
```

As I am only interested in obtaining the correlation coefficients for "Group_B" I have modified the `R2_df` function to account for filtering the data frame based on the presence of "Group_2". This updated code is provided below. I do not receive any errors when I run this updated code, but all of the R2 values are now NA.

```
R2 = function(y_actual,y_predict){
  cor(y_actual,y_predict)^2
}

R2_df <- function(dataset, x, y, z){
  
  r2_dataset <- dataset %>% filter(z == "Group_2")
  
  R2(r2_dataset[[x]], r2_dataset[[y]])
  
}
    
Var_list <- df %>% select(starts_with("Var")) %>% colnames()
New_Var_list <- df %>% select(starts_with("New")) %>% colnames()
Control_list <- df %>% select(starts_with("ControlVar")) %>% colnames()

mapply(R2_df, Var_list, New_Var_list, Control_list, MoreArgs = list(dataset = df))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated Answer, after Clarification in Comments

The problem is, the `filter( z == "Group_2")` call. Because z does not get replaced by the character it contains (in the first case `ControlVarA`) but instead dplyr will try to find a column called `z` in your data.frame.

You can solve that by specifing to look for the character type column-name saved in `z` through indexing with: `[]` the data passed by the `%>%` pipe `.`, e.g.:
`r2_dataset <- dataset %>% filter(.[z] == "Group_2")`

```
library(dplyr)

R2 = function(y_actual,y_predict){
  cor(y_actual,y_predict)^2
}



R2_df <- function( x, y, z, dataset){
  r2_dataset <- dataset %>% filter(.[z] == "Group_2")
  R2(r2_dataset[[x]], r2_dataset[[y]])
  
}

Var_list <- df %>% select(starts_with("Var")) %>% colnames()
New_Var_list <- df %>% select(starts_with("New")) %>% colnames()
Control_list <- df %>% select(starts_with("ControlVar")) %>% colnames()

mapply(R2_df, Var_list, New_Var_list ,Control_list, MoreArgs = list(dataset = df))
```

#### Output

```
      VarA       VarB       VarC       VarD 
0.01513781 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000
```

Comment: Thanks Bjorn. I Made a mistake with my initial example, in that I didnt provide the example data frame with different ControlVar columns for columns ControlVarA, ControlVarB, ControlVarC and ControlVarD. I have updated the question (sorry about that). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this now what you intended? Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, much appreciated! This solves my issue